# exporting MongoDB to CSV using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like write a script to generate a CSV file from my mongoDB database and I would like to know the most convenient version !

first let me begin with the structure of collections.

```
MyDataBase -> setting
              users
              fruits
```

in setting I have something like

```
setting -> _id
           data
           _tenant
```

and the thing I am after, is making a CSV file out of profiles in *data*
which they have some fields/properties like "name", "address", "postalcode", "email", age and etc. and not neccessary all of these profile have all files/properties and even some of them look like collection (have sub-branches) which I am not interested in at all !

so, my code is python so far is look like these

```
myquery = db.settings.find() # I am getting everything !
output = csv.writer(open('some.csv', 'wt')) # writng in this file

for items in myquery[0:10]: # first 11 entries
    a = list(items['data']['Profile'].values()) # collections are importent as dictionary and I am making them as list
    tt = list()
    for chiz in a:
        if chiz is not None:
            tt.append(chiz.encode('ascii', 'ignore')) #encoding
        else:
            tt.append("none")
    output.writerow(tt)
```

these fields/properties dont have neccessary all fields, and also even some of them are collection(with sub-branch) and will be imported as dictionary ! so, I have to convert them to list and all and all, there are quite few things to take care in such a process and in all doesn't look that straightforward!

Is it a typical way to make such report? If not, can someone make it clear?

Comment: Have you tried [mongoexport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport)?  It will export a collection to CSV and may save you the effort of rolling your own tool.

Comment: well, I wish "mongoexport" was working in python as well ! or there was some nice IDE for mongodb to be able to play with csv/table format like, easier.

Comment: There are several different [Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs), but "nice" is subjective as everyone has different requirements and preferences.  One lateral option you might want to look into is a [reporting tool](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Business+Intelligence).  For example, Jasper/[iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) is a visual report designer that supports MongoDB and can export to multiple formats including CSV.

Comment: There are couple of approaches for this scenario. (1) Using `mongoexport` command line tool to create the CSV. Create a view on the collection(s) - the view takes an aggregation pipeline for performing all the data transformation - filters, mapping, lookups, reducing, projection, etc. Run the export by specifying the view in the `mongoexport`'s `--collection` option (just like you use a collection). (2)...

Comment: (2) Using PyMongo, MongoDB Python driver. Create an aggregation pipeline on the collection(s) within the Python program using PyMongo APIs for all the data transformation. Run the pipeline and the output is used to write to the CSV. Use the Python CSV module's `csv.writer` function or `csv.DictWriter` class to write the pipeline output to the csv file.